# XSL element with multiple namespace with different prefix

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, prefix

I wanna create an element in my XSL 1.0 with some namespace Just like this:

```
<element xmlns:a = '...' xmlns:b = '...' xmlns = '...' >
```

For some reason I can't use XSL 2.0, with `<xsl:namespace>` extension, there is only one allowed namespace declared for each element in XSL 1.0,how should I do?

Regards,

Comment: I'm not aware of there being any limitation to the number of namespace declarations in XSLT 1.0, can you clarify with an small example XSLT that doesn't work for you?

Comment: I tell ya, my brother, I _wanna_ show ya'll a thing about the ghetto.

Comment: When the serializer outputs the result of your transformation it should ensure that all the in-scope namespace mappings are in place at all the right places, but you can't force it to include a particular namespace _declaration_ at a particular place.  For example, if you try and output an `<element xmlns:a="urn:foo">` in a context where the `a` prefix is already bound to the `urn:foo` namespace in the parent scope, then the serializer is free to omit the `xmlns:a` on `<element>` without changing the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

If I make the file `test.xsl` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <multins xmlns:abc="http://example.com/1" xmlns:def="http://example.com/2" />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then run it

```
xsltproc test.xsl test.xsl
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><multins xmlns:abc="http://example.com/1" xmlns:def="http://example.com/2"/></root>
```

with this version info :

```
$ xsltproc --version
Using libxml 20703, libxslt 10124 and libexslt 813
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20632, libxslt 10124 and libexslt 813
libxslt 10124 was compiled against libxml 20632
libexslt 813 was compiled against libxml 20632
```

Comment: Actually I transform the XSL in a c# program for some reason. The result is not the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

Try the W3C XSLT 2.0 Spec: [Creating Namespace Nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-namespace-nodes). The gist of it is that you can create  elements within other elements to put those namespaces into scope.

```
Example:

<!--XSLT 2.0-->
<data xsi:type="xs:integer" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:namespace name="xs" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'"/>
  <xsl:text>42</xsl:text>
</data>

<!--XSLT 1.0-->
<data xsi:type="xs:integer"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  42
</data>
```

Comment: yeah I know that the XSL 2.0 supports the < xsl: namespace > extension

Comment: For I transform the XSL in the c# program, which doesn't support XSL 2.0 in its System.xml.xsl namespace, so XSL 1.0 is the only choice

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your question, so you should post an answer of your own.